# sqlite database locking

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I would like to know about the locking method in sqlite. I am using some python scripts using sqlalchemy to write to sqlite db. There are lot of scripts writing to the db simultaneously and I am getting database locked errors frequently. Can we enable locking per table for sqlite?. Is sqlite suitable for lot of parallel writes?

Comment: Mhmm, maybe a better place to ask: https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=sqlite+locking

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is most likely not the best solution as it won't allow simultaneous writes ([Source](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5)).

You're better off with a server/client database like Postgres in this situation. Since you're already using an ORM it should be as easy as changing the connection string.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, sqlite is not suitable for concurrent writes.